# Get friendship start date

Tags: facebook-graph-api, social-network-friendship

I've been looking for a way to know the date two users became friends. I've found [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4874014/how-can-i-get-friendship-details-in-facebook-graph-api) but it only explains how to simulate the friendship page with multiple FQL queries.

What I want to determine is the date you can see at the top of the friendship page ("Facebook friends since...").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This date isn't available via the Graph API or FQL tables. You can log a feature request with Facebook or get creative with workarounds such as those you linked in the post.

Answer (score 10):

I've done this in a way which is admittedly a bit hackish. You can use the [posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) endpoint to get all posts, then select the posts that contain the words "now friends". The `story_tags` field will contain an object describing the details of the friend. In rails, you can use the [facebook gem](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) to do this:

```
# To retrieve your friendship start dates
user = {fb_id: <your fb id>, auth_token: <your fb auth token>}
fb_user = FbGraph::User.me(user[:auth_token])
posts = fb_user.posts(:since => 10.days.ago.to_i, :until => Time.now.to_i)
posts = posts.reject{|p| p.story.nil? || (!p.story.include?("now friends"))}
posts.each do |p|
  p.story_tags.each do |t|
    unless t.identifier == user[:fb_id]
      puts "You became friends with #{t.name} at #{p.created_time}"
    end
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
You became friends with Christina Ricci at 2013-01-12 20:34:58 UTC
You became friends with Michael Jordon at 2013-01-09 19:51:51 UTC
You became friends with Barack Obama at 2013-01-04 19:06:51 UTC
```